# Show that $ab^* + a^*b \geq bb^*$ is always true for all $a,b \in \mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-numbers, alternative-proof

The product of the sum of two complex numbers is in the form
$$(a+b)(a^*+b^*) = aa^* + bb^* + ab^* + a^*b$$
where  $a,b \in \mathbb{C}$ and $aa^*\geq bb^*$.

**Claim**

Is this equation
$$ab^* + a^*b \geq bb^*$$

always true or in what condition this can be true?

**My effort**

I have tried proving it but I can think of a number $b=i$ that leads me to

$$\mp \text{Im}\{2a\} \geq 1$$

which I suppose disproves the claim when $a$ has no imaginary component.

I am looking for a way to make the claim *always true* by adjusting the condition: $aa^*\geq bb^*$ or adding other condition.

Comment: Why should that be always true? It's not even  true in general when $a$ and $b$ are real.

Comment: @Tobsn, if $a,b \in \mathbb{R}, a \geq b$, I suppose $2ab \geq b^2$ always holds.

Comment: $a=1$ and $b=-1$

Comment: Sorry. I should say $|2ab|\geq b^2$.

Comment: If you go to polar coordinates, you immediately see that a reasonable condition independent of the absolute values (except of course for the condition $|a|\ge |b|$( is that the angle between the two is at most $60$ degrees in absolute value

Comment: @Conrad do you mean that $|\angle{a}-\angle{b}| \leq 60$?

Comment: Yes because the required condition is $\cos(\phi-\theta)\ge |b|/(2|a|)$ so if the cosine is at least $1/2$ that happens under the only condition on the absolute values from the post

Comment: I got your point @Conrad. Thank you for pointing that out. I think I will now be able to prove it with that condition. If you have a better way to complete the proof, you may want to post them. Thank you.

Comment: Your inequality is equivalent to $aa^\ast\geq(a-b)(a-b)^\ast$ or equivalently, $|a|\geq|a-b|$.

Comment: @user1551, sorry, I don't see how you have arrived to that when $aa^* \geq bb^*$? Any hint please?

Comment: @EddyPiedad That's not using the condition $|a|^2 \ge |b|^2$ at all, but it's simply manipulating your target inequality to rewrite it as $|a|^2 \ge |a-b|^2 \iff |a| \ge |a-b|$.

Comment: As suggested by Conrad, is it correct to say $cos(\phi-\theta) \geq |a-b|/|a|$? Thanks @dxiv.

Comment: @dxiv I posted an answer. Does the answer follows your line of thought?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modifying the given condition from $|a| \geq |b|$ to $|a| \geq |a-b|$, the claim
$$ab^* + a^*b \geq bb^*$$ is always true $a,b \in \mathbb{C}$.

**Proof**

From the condition,
$$|a| \geq |a-b|$$
$$aa^* \geq (a-b)(a-b)^*$$
$$aa^* \geq (a-b)(a^*-b^*)$$
$$aa^* \geq aa^*-ab^*-a^*b+bb^*$$
$$0 \geq bb^*-ab^*-a^*b$$
$$ab^*+a^*b \geq bb^* \blacksquare$$

Comment: This actually proves the equivalence $|a| \geq |a-b| \iff ab^*+a^*b \geq bb^*$ since all steps are reversible.

Comment: Yes. Thank you.