# What are the set/range/domain of the complex numbers $a, b$ so that satisfy this inequality $|a| \geq |a-b|$?

Tags: complex-numbers, solution-verification

From my previous [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4441997), this inequality $|a| \geq |a-b|$ is **not** true $\forall a,b \in \mathbb{C}$. For example, $a=1, b=-0.5$.

What are the set/range/domain of the complex numbers $a, b$ so that satisfy this inequality?

Someone suggested this
$$\cos(\theta_a-\theta_b) \geq |b|/|a|$$

and it makes sense but I don't know how where it comes from or how to explain it.

Comment: Your proof looks fine but it's not clear what you're asking. You want to modify the claim so that it holds for any pair of complex numbers? Well, not a lot of interesting things hold for *any* pair of complex numbers, so what result are you looking for here?

Comment: I have just edited for clarification.

Comment: So you're asking for alternative ways to describe the condition $|a| \geq |a-b|$? Because "what domain of $\mathbb{C}$ so that this holds" is tautological - you're describing it exactly with this condition, i.e., "let $a, b\in \mathbb{C}$ such that $|a| \geq |a-b|$.

Comment: That's right I got it. I should remove that $a,b \in \mathbb{C}$ to avoid confusion. I would like to get the boundaries of $a, b$ that satisfy the condition.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm still not understanding what you're after. You *have* a condition already. You're just looking for alternate ways to describe it? An example of why I am confused : it's a bit like saying "how can I get the boundaries of $x-y=2$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$"? When, you've already done so just by asking the question.

Comment: Sorry I edited again. I wanted to know the set that satisfies the inequality $|a| \geq |a-b|$. I hope this is clearer.

Comment: Again, this is like saying "I want to understand the set of real numbers $x$ such that $x>2$." You have already described exactly that set. You want the set of complex numbers satisfying some inequality, ok, well, you have it. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes that makes sense. Sorry. I am confused how to express what I'm looking for but I'm sure I understand what you mean. Thanks.

Comment: @EddyPiedad The inequality means $b$ is on or inside the circle centered at $a$ that passes through the origin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a=|a|(\cos\theta_a+i\sin\theta_a)$, $b=|b|(\cos\theta_b+i\sin\theta_b)$, hence $$|a-b|^2=|a|^2+|b|^2-2|a||b|\cos(\theta_{a}-\theta_b).$$

Your condition becomes then
\begin{align}
|a|^2\ge|a|^2+|b|^2-2|a||b|\cos(\theta_{a}-\theta_b) \iff & 0\ge|b|^2-2|a||b|\cos(\theta_{a}-\theta_b)\\
\iff & 2|a||b|\cos(\theta_{a}-\theta_b)\ge|b|^2\\
\iff & \cos(\theta_{a}-\theta_b)\ge|b|/2|a|.
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you @ecrin. This is what I'm looking for.